# Can a column's server_defaults be different for different dialects in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy to configure my database schemas, and I want to set up a `Column` with a `server_default` that is different depending on the database dialect. One database function call for PostgreSQL and another for SQLite. Can this be done? How?

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, DateTime    

class CustomNow():
    pass # What to do?

class Timestamps(object):
    created = Column(DateTime, server_default=CustomNow())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `@compiles` decorartor, as described in [the docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/compiler.html?highlight=compiles#dialect-specific-compilation-rules):

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.compiler import compiles
from sqlalchemy.sql.functions import FunctionElement


class CustomNow(FunctionElement):
    name = "custom_now"


@compiles(CustomNow)
def visit_custom_now(element, compiler, **kwargs):
    return "(NOW())"


@compiles(CustomNow, "sqlite")
def visit_custom_now_for_sqlite(element, compiler, **kwargs):
    return "(DATETIME('now', 'localtime'))"
```